# NSTextField has no member 'text'

Tags: xcode, swift, macos

I am creating a Mac application with Xcode, Swift

I got this error (in the title) on this code

```
let email = self.emailTextField.text
```

I thought it would be the same as I did on my iOS application.

Do you guys know what the problem is?

Comment: `NSTextField` may not have a member `text`, but it has a perfectly good set of documentation.

Comment: If you feel your quest has been answered, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 6):

[`NSTextField`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextField_Class/) has a member called [`stringValue`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSControl_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSControl/setStringValue:) instead of [`text`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextView/text).

Try: `let email = self.emailTextField.stringValue`